# open DropdownButton items list below the hint text

Tags: flutter, dropdown, dropdownbutton

How to open DropdownButton items list below the hint text not over the whole button

If you look at Flutter example with the link below you will see when you click at "One" item it will open all dropdown items over the dropdown.

I need that "One" item should still appear and items opens below "One" like image below?
[image]
How to fix it without using another package

```
 Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 11),
      height: 50,
      child: DropdownButton<dynamic>(
        hint:  Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
          child: Text('Choose type',  textScaleFactor: 1.2,
            style: TextStyle(color:  Colors.grey ),),
        ),
        value: type,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        iconSize: 40,
        iconEnabledColor: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 16,
        itemHeight: 90,
        isExpanded: true,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        isDense: false,
        underline: Divider(height: 0, color: Colors.black, ),

        onChanged: (val) {

          if(val != null) {
            setState(() {
              type = val;
            });
          }
        },
        items: types_view.types_list.map<DropdownMenuItem>(( value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: value,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
              child: Text(value.toString(), textScaleFactor: 1.2, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you share your dropdown code?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I putted the code now

Comment: Try to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68272167/13997210 hope it helps you , if it not solved your problem let me know

Comment: It not solved my problem, the dropdown items still shows over the dropdown, I put a design image for what I need

Comment: please check my answer hope it helps you

Comment: Unfortunately It not helped, can you look at the image I added above, I want that items list shows below "One" as you see in the image

Comment: There's no easy way to force it, the overlay will always try to find the best place to render the dropdown list.

Comment: @blue492,ok Try to here may it helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859741/13997210 or use dropdown below package here https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_below

Comment: Thanks, can we redesign DropDownButton like putting it in another widget to open the items as we want in the place we need?

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code hope it helpful for you:

Create dropdown item list and declare one variable :

```
 String getMonthwiseGraph;

 List monthsList = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ];
```

Create Widget like Container that declare dropdown button

```
 Container(
            width: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.grey,
                style: BorderStyle.solid,
              ),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10,
              left: 90,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
                hint: Text(
                  'Select Month',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                value: getMonthwiseGraph,
                onChanged: (String monthNewValue) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      getMonthwiseGraph = monthNewValue;
                    },
                  );
                },
                items: monthsList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                  (value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(
                        value,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your output screen like -> [image]

Comment: Thanks, can we redesign DropDownButton like putting it in another widget to open the items as we want in the place we need?+

Comment: Ok now you want dropdown selected value is set to other class/other widget? if your problem is solved so accept my answer and upvote it

Comment: No, the problem is not solved. With your solution the items still appear over the dropdownbutton.  Do you have another solution? I mean another widget which prevent the items appear over dropdownbutton